# Mixed node in nokogiri

Tags: nokogiri

I want to make a node that has both text content and an attribute with Nokogiri. E.g. I want to produce XML:

```
<root blah="value">text content</root>
```

I try to do this with:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do 
  root(:blah=>"value") "text content"
end
```

But Ruby complains with:

```
create-config.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
  root(:blah => "value") "text content"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, learn some Ruby syntax for your own good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to use `{}` and `text`

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do
  root(:blah => "value") { 
    text("text content") 
}
end
```